# Hooking on to abbreviation expansion

Tags: hooks, advice, abbrev

I don't know exactly how `abbrev-mode` works, but I suppose certain
keys --spaces and stops-- cause an examination of the word before
point, and a replacement of it in some cases.  My question is how one
might hook on to that mechanism, say to encrypt every word typed, at
abbreviation-expansion time.  Methods that do not make use of
`abbrev-mode` are also welcome, and probably preferable.

Comment: Customize `pre-abbrev-expand-hook`.

Comment: `C-h o pre-abbrev-expand-hook` says: `This variable is obsolete since 23.1; use ‘abbrev-expand-function’ instead.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abbrev-expand-function` for that.  But you could also use `post-self-insert-hook` in order to be independent from `abbrev-mode`.